# Could not resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using `Android Studio 2.1.3` and am trying to learn `Android` coding from an `Udacity` course. Could not resolve `x` keeps on popping up.

What should i do?

Which are the basic syntaxes in which `Android Studio v1.0` and the current versions?

```
package raggedy_man.sunshine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
                        String[] data = {
                                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                              "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                               "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
                        };
             List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
    // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    mForecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    weekForecast)
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Press `ALT+ENTER` on your indicated error line and import `R`

Comment: Import R mate!!

Answer (score 0):

Please add:

```
import <yourcompanyname>.com.<yourappname>.R
```

or go to the line of code where you are getting the error. you will se a blue box appear. Press:

**ALT + ENTER**

and Android Studio will import it for you.

Comment: I tried ALT+ENTER, android studio asks me to set it as a variable